# Como Generar mensajes de alertas con fechas.?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, datatables

Estoy creando `listado` con el `plug-in` `DataTable`. Hasta el momento ahí todo bien.
Uso `php`, `js` y `mysql` `MVC`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en ella se encuentra el registro `Fecha Próxima etapa`.

Busco poder agregar un mensaje de `alerta` en la columna de observaciones. donde si la `Fecha Próxima etapa` es mayor a la `fecha actual`, me avise que ya se paso "x" días y si es menor que faltan "x" días.

este es mi `código` con el cual listo mi tabla

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-default box-solid">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title"> <b> CERDOS REPRODUCIDOS</b> </h3>

            <!-- /.box-tools -->
        </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="global_filter form-control" id="global_filter" placeholder="Ingresar dato a buscar">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                    </div><br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" style="width:100%" onclick="AbrirModalRegistroReproducidos()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Nuevo Registro</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table id="listar_reproducidos" class="display responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Fecha de Registro</th>
                        <th>Tatuaje</th>
                        <th>Madre</th>
                        <th>Padre</th>
                        <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                        <th>Sexo</th>
                        <th>Peso Promedio KG</th>
                        <th>Peso Real KG</th>
                        <th>Etapa</th>
                        <th>Fecha Proxima Etapa</th>
                        <th>Moviento</th>
                        <th>Acci&oacute;n</th>
                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Fecha de Registro</th>
                        <th>Tatuaje</th>
                        <th>Madre</th>
                        <th>Padre</th>
                        <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
                        <th>Sexo</th>
                        <th>Peso Promedio KG</th>
                        <th>Peso Real KG</th>
                        <th>Etapa</th>
                        <th>Fecha Proxima Etapa</th>
                        <th>Moviento</th>
                        <th>Acci&oacute;n</th>
                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>

</div>
```

y este mi `js` con el que traigo los datos de la `BD`

```
var table;
function listar_reproducidos(){
     table = $("#listar_reproducidos").DataTable({
       "ordering":true,   
       "bLengthChange":true,
       "searching": { "regex": false },
       "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
       "pageLength": 10,
       "destroy":true,
       "async": false ,
       "processing": true,
       "ajax":{
           "url":"../controlador/reproducidos/controlador_reproducidos_listar.php",
           type:'POST'
       },
       "columns":[
           {"data":"posicion"},
           {"data":"cerp_fecharegistro"},
           {"data":"cerp_tatuaje"},
           {"data":"reproh_tatuaje"},
           {"data":"reprom_tatuaje"},
           {"data":"cerp_fechanacimiento"},
           {"data":"cerp_sexo",
           render: function (data, type, row ) {
               if(data=='M'){
                   return "MACHO";                   
               }else{
                   return "HEMBRA";                 
               }
           }
      },
           {"data":"cerp_pesopromedio"},
           {"data":"cerp_pesoreal"},
           {"data":"eta_nombre"},
           {"data":"cerp_fechafinaletapa"},
           {"data":"mov_nombre",
           render: function (data, type, row ) {
            if(data=='ACTIVO'){
                return "<span class='label label-success'>"+data+"</span>";                   
            }else{
              return "<span class='label label-danger'>"+data+"</span>";                 
            }
          }
        },
           {"defaultContent":"<button style='font-size:13px;' type='button' class='editar btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button>&nbsp;"},
           {"defaultContent":""}
       ],

       "language":idioma_espanol,
       select: true
   });
   document.getElementById("listar_reproducidos_filter").style.display="none";
   $('input.global_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
        filterGlobal();
    } );
    $('input.column_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
        filterColumn( $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column') );
    });

}
```

Muchas Gracias de ante mano y Bendiciones

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema en concreto?

Comment: Busco poder agregar un mensaje de alerta en la columna de observaciones. donde si la Fecha Próxima etapa es mayor a la fecha actual(hoy), me avise que ya se paso "x" días y si es menor que faltan "x" días.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te indico como quedaría la parte de JavaScript, pruébalo a ver si te he entendido bien.

```
  var table;
  function listar_reproducidos(){
       table = $("#listar_reproducidos").DataTable({
         "ordering":true,   
         "bLengthChange":true,
         "searching": { "regex": false },
         "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
         "pageLength": 10,
         "destroy":true,
         "async": false ,
         "processing": true,
         "ajax":{
             "url":"../controlador/reproducidos/controlador_reproducidos_listar.php",
             type:'POST'
         },
         "columns":[
             {"data":"posicion"},
             {"data":"cerp_fecharegistro"},
             {"data":"cerp_tatuaje"},
             {"data":"reproh_tatuaje"},
             {"data":"reprom_tatuaje"},
             {"data":"cerp_fechanacimiento"},
             {"data":"cerp_sexo",
             render: function (data, type, row ) {
                 if(data=='M'){
                     return "MACHO";                   
                 }else{
                     return "HEMBRA";                 
                 }
             }
        },
             {"data":"cerp_pesopromedio"},
             {"data":"cerp_pesoreal"},
             {"data":"eta_nombre"},
             {"data":"cerp_fechafinaletapa",
                         render: function (data, type, row ) {
                            var hoy = moment(new Date());
                            var fechafinaletapa = moment(new Date(data));
                            diasdiferencia = hoy.diff(fechafinaletapa, 'days');
                            return data;
                         }
             },
             {"data":"mov_nombre",
             render: function (data, type, row ) {
              if(data=='ACTIVO'){
                  return "<span class='label label-success'>"+data+"</span>";                   
              }else{
                return "<span class='label label-danger'>"+data+"</span>";                 
              }
            }
          },
             {"defaultContent":"<button style='font-size:13px;' type='button' class='editar btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button>&nbsp;"},
             {"defaultContent":"",
                          render: function () {
                             if (diasdiferencia > 0) {
                                return "<span class='laquesea'>Te has pasado " + diasdiferencia + " días</span>";
                             }
                             if (diasdiferencia < 0) {
                                return "<span class='laquesea'>Te faltan " + Math.abs(diasdiferencia) + " días</span>";
                             }
                          }
             }
         ],

         "language":idioma_espanol,
         select: true
     });
     document.getElementById("listar_reproducidos_filter").style.display="none";
     $('input.global_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
          filterGlobal();
      } );
      $('input.column_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
          filterColumn( $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column') );
      });
```

Comment: me calcula los días correctamente. pero ahora no me muestra la fecha próxima etapa.

Comment: ya lo solucione, buscando en la documentación de Data Tables. solo tenia que retornar la data.

Comment: Sorry, se me olvidó retornar la fecha, modifico el código para futuras consultas. Márcalo como contestado ;-)

Comment: Muchas Gracias por su ayuda. Realmente se le agradece mucho.

Comment: A mandar, para eso es esta comunidad, suerte!!!

Answer (score 1):

yo utilizo la librería moment.js para el manejo de fechas, formatos, agregar o quitar dias, meses, años, horas, segundos, etc... y muchas más funciones. La puedes descargar desde https://momentjs.com/ en dos versiones moment.js y moment-with-locales.js, la segunda tiene además herramientas para el formato internacional, pero para tu caso con la primera tienes suficiente.
Utilizando esta librería el código sería algo así.

```
// Creamos objeto "hoy" con la fecha actual
var hoy = moment(new Date()); 
// Capturamos la fecha del campo "cerp_fechafinaletapa", como ya tiene un formato valido
// según la imágen de la tabla (YYYY-MM-DD), no has de formatearla.
var fechafinaletapa = moment(new Date(Valor_de_cerp_fechafinaletapa));
// Obtenemos variable con la diferencia de días
var diasdiferencia = hoy.diff(fechafinaletapa, 'days');
```

Con esto tendrías la diferencia de días, ahora solo tienes que crear un if donde vayas a poner el valor para "Observaciones" según la diferencia de días.
Espero haberme explicado bien, un saludo.

Comment: Me puedes terminar de ayudar a crear el If por favor?